# Axios post returns empty object while uploading a file

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, react-redux, multipartform-data, form-data

Hi Currently I am trying to upload a file with get method with Axios but when i am pushing the file it getting the file as object (I need to upload json file)

current action file

1. [Current action file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfcLt.png)

plce where the action is getting called
[action call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAYvY.png)

in console log i am able to see the files
[json file that need to be uploaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swQyN.png)

but in payload when i see it in header I am getting empty object in file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXz1g.png)

Comment: Please read [ask]. In particular the part about not posting pictures of text.

Answer (score 0):

Axios POST takes data as its second argument. If you simply want to POST with params you need to pass an empty object `{}` or `null` as the second argument.